# Confusion about bootstrap Cards with React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have the below code:

```
import { Card, CardGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

function Woodcutting() {
  const trees = [
    {
      uID: "tree-normal",
      name: "Normal Tree",
      level: 1,
      interval: 3000,
      xp: 10,
      media: "tree.png",
    },
    {
      uid: "tree-oak",
      name: "Oak Tree",
      level: 5,
      interval: 4000,
      xp: 15,
      media: "tree.png",
    },
    {
      uID: "tree-magic",
      name: "Magic Tree",
      level: 10,
      interval: 5000,
      xp: 20,
      media: "tree.png",
    },
  ];

  function onCardClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <CardGroup>
      {trees.map((tree) => (
        <Card
          style={{ width: "18rem" }}
          onClick={onCardClick}
          key={tree.uID}
          value={tree.uID}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          {/* <Card.Img variant="top" src="tree.png" /> */}
          <Card.Body>{tree.name}</Card.Body>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </CardGroup>
  );
}

export default Woodcutting;
```

I'm a little confused on a couple of things.

First, even though I've set the "key" prop on  I'm still getting a warning in the console saying "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Second, even though I've set the "value" prop, when I log to the console on each click I get "undefined". Is anybody able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)second object's key "uID" is mistyped that's causing key issue

2)Card might not have a value prop.
and it is not a form element

Replace your onClick with:

```
onClick={()=>onCardClick(tree.uID)}
```

and

```
 function onCardClick(uID) {
    console.log(uID);
  }
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, updating the onClick like you said fixed that problem.

Comment: I'm still getting the warning for "key" even after correcting the typo though, any ideas?

Comment: Are you having problem with the same data provided above or you're implementing with different data?Plus you need to cross check if the warning is giving to this component or some other component

Comment: @Cypher236 is your problem fixed?